# Creating a Maintenance Plan for a SQL Azure Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, maintenance-plans

I need to create a maintenance plan for a number of SQL Azure databases.  Unfortunately, my *many* years of experience as a SQL Server DBA does not include experience with this task (sarcasm intended).

After a quick search, I found some information in an article [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/tim/sqlskills-sql101-database-maintenance-for-azure-sql-database/).  Using the information in this article and not knowing whether or not there was a *better* option, I decided upon using the second option (Database Maintenance Plans).  What follows makes the assumption that I understand the process correctly.

Using a local instance of SQL Server, I created a new maintenance plan.  From there, I added a new connection to one of the SQL Azure databases by using the **Manage Connections** option.  From there, I added a task to the designer pane.  I used the task for updating statistics but I imagine it could have been any other task.  Editing the properties of the task, I selected a single database.  That is about as far as I made it.  What follows is some of the observations I have made.

- By default in the **Update Statistics Task** property page, the
  option **Tables and Views** is selected for the **Object** item.  If
  I change this option in my environment (for the SQL Azure database),
  the dialog is immediately closed (almost as though it has crashed).
- If I re-open the **Update Statistics Task** property page and then
  click the **View T-SQL** button, an error is generated indicated that
  login failed for the specified user.  From there, I re-opened the
  **Manage Connections** dialog and checked the properties of the connection to SQL Azure and noticed that the password is blank
  (almost as though the password is not being retained anywhere).
- If I use a database on the local server this issue does not exist.

Am I proceeding in the *correct* direction?  If so, is there something I am missing?  Is there a *better* or more *correct* way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a maintenance plan on a local SQL Server instance to perform maintenance tasks on an Azure SQL database, consider creating a runbook using Azure Automation. The runbook should run  a PowerShell script like the following:

```
$AzureSQLServerName = "<ServerName>"
$AzureSQLDatabaseName = "<DatabaseName>"

$AzureSQLServerName = $AzureSQLServerName + ".database.windows.net"
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "SQLLogin"
$SQLOutput = $(Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $AzureSQLServerName -Username $Cred.UserName -Password $Cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password -Database $AzureSQLDatabaseName -Query "exec [dbo].[AzureSQLMaintenance] @Operation='all' ,@LogToTable=1" -QueryTimeout 65535 -ConnectionTimeout 60 -Verbose) 4>&1

Write-Output $SQLOutput
```

Please read detailed information [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2018/01/15/automating-azure-sql-db-index-and-statistic-maintenance-using-azure-automation/).